# Automatically updating a set of TVs when another TV is changed by the user

Tags: modx-revolution

I have the following in MODX revo 2.2:

I defined 5 Template Variables which represent a pricing structure. One of the TV's represents the base price and is maintained (in the manager) by the user while the others should be automatically calculated as a known percentage of the base price. So what I want is that when the user changes the base price the other 4 TV's are automatically (re)calculated.

I tried implementing this by defining an `@EVAL` binding for the 4 TV's and calling a snippet, however I was not successful with that approach. Even just a simple `@EVAL return 100;` would leave the TVs blank.

I also had a look at plugins to solve this and found various system events that fire when working with TV's. This suggests that this would be a method to implement this.

Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: Can we see some code? It sounds to me like your 4 other TV's don't need to be TV's at all [unless they need to be modified on a per resource basis?] but may be better served as snippets in your template running a calculation from the one base price TV. 

Also - be careful with the system events, while there are quite a few there to work with, not all of them are actually implemented. [I found out the hard way]

Comment: They could vary on a per resource basis. The actual percentages are stored as TVs in another resource. I have no code other than the TV definitions which are numbers. I toyed with the @EVAL binding but was not successful.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion about implementing as snippets. That actually worked. If you post it as an answer, I will accept. Nonetheless weird that the @EVAL binding did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we see some code? It sounds to me like your 4 other TV's don't need to be TV's at all [unless they need to be modified on a per resource basis?] but may be better served as snippets in your template running a calculation from the one base price TV. Also - be careful with the system events, while there are quite a few there to work with, not all of them are actually implemented. [I found out the hard way] –

Thanks Roger.  I do spend a lot of time trying to find ways to NOT use TVs as they can become very expensive to process. If at anytime you look at a TV and think it will work as a snippet [or chunk or plugin] then that's probably going to be the way to go. IMHO.

Glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to sum the content of two template variables in MODX Evolution 1.0.3:

```
@EVAL $tvs=array('Fee_year_1','Fee_year_2');$tarifs=$modx->getTemplateVarOutput($tvs,'39');return $tarifs['Fee_year_1']+$tarifs['Fee_year_2'];
```

This is put in a Template Variable with type "Number", which is displayed as placeholder in a Ditto chunk: [+Total_2_years+]

If using the TV as a placeholder, you must specify the document id explicitely.
A drawback is that I was obliged to set the document identifer manually.
Neither [+id+] nor strval($modx->documentIdentifier) worked.

I believe using a snippet is much better in this case.